# Execute code after reader has finished reading ENTIRE message

Tags: c#, loops, tcp, tcpclient, streamreader

I would like to achieve the following result. 
After the http message is fully read by the streamreader, I want to get the host of the request (which I don't think will be an issue) and start a tcp client to that host.

[Code I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9hQe.png)

Since the comment is in the while true loop it loops. But I thought readline() was blocking so it would only get executed once.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could solve this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following code, to avoid redundancy (peeking the `StreamReader` to only then use the value). [There are reports in this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376887/c-using-streamreader-to-read-line-from-txt-file-but-peek-return-1-even-the) of people having the same issue with `Peek`.

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Use the line
}
```

Comment: @fhcimiolin but then inside that while loop i would only have a partial message, I want to be "notified" when the whole message has been received

Comment: @juser But `ReadLine` does essentially that - it reads the next line and assigns it to `line`, for you to use inside the loop. When the whole message has been received, that is - when all the lines have been read, then the while loop is exited and you can proceed. That is just the 'usual way' to read lines from a `StreamReader`, and a suggestion for you to try and see if it works any better.